# Get multiple cookies and put into variable by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application that uses cookies. A new cookie is created as an item with multiple values each time the user clicks "Add". The name of the cookie is increased by 1 each time.

Example cookies would be like below:

```
Cookie 1 - 1=value[] stuff[] things[] ect[];
Cookie 2 - 2=value[] stuff[] things[] whatever[];
Cookie 3 - 3=value[] stuff[] things[] 15[];
```

The user can also remove items which will delete the cookie.
So for example, user clicks Delete on cookie one, then only cookie 2 and 3 remain.

Those cookies are then added to a table that is visible and later submitted by XML when the user clicks Submit.

I need, on submit, to search for all cookies by **name** to see which ones exist. Then to take the cookies' values and add them to variables and then insert to the table. Each cookie will have 14 different values. I've got the adding cookies part figured out. The problem is checking when cookies exist.

The function below adds the row to the table when the user clicks Add:

```
createCookie(lineItem, ShipLineDesc +'[]' + ShipLineEccn +'[]' + ShipLineQty + '[]' + ShipLineOrg +'[]' 
        + ShipLineSchb +'[]' +ShipLineSchBDesc +'[]' + ShipLinePQty + '[]' + ShipLinePUom +'[]' 
        + ShipLineSQty + '[]' + ShipLineSUom +'[]' + ShipLineWeight +'[]' + ShipLineTotalWeight 
        + '[]' + ShipLineValue +'[]' + ShipLineTotalValue, 9999);

    // Read Cookie.
getLine(lineItem);



function getLine(lineItem) {
    // If a cookie doesn't exist, return false. Otherwise, insert in to table.
    if (document.cookie == "") { return false; }
    else {
        // Insert line item from Cookie to table.   
        var vals = readCookie(lineItem).split('[]');
        for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
            a1=vals[0];
            b1=vals[1];
            c1=vals[2];
            d1=vals[3];
            e1=vals[4];
            f1=vals[5];
            g1=vals[6];
            h1=vals[7];
            i1=vals[8];
            j1=vals[9];
            k1=vals[10];
            l1=vals[11];
            m1=vals[12];
            n1=vals[13];
        }
        $('#lineItemTable tr:last').after("<tr id='lineItemTd"+lineItem+"'><td style='border-left:0px;'>"+a1+"</td><td>"+e1+"</td><td>"+f1+"</td><td>"+c1+"</td><td>"+k1+"</td><td>"+m1+"</td><td>"+l1+"</td><td>"+n1+"</td>" 
            + "<td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick='editLine("+lineItem+");' /> <input type='button' value='Del' onclick='delLine("+lineItem+");' /></td></tr>");

        // Change lineItem number for next line.
        addTheLine();
        clearForm();
    }
}
// End
```

I need to figure out how to check which cookies already exist by their name (reading all cookies by their name, getting values for each one).
The names will always be 1-10.

Read cookie function is below:

```
function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}

// Create Cookie
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = ";expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+";path=/";
}
```

Comment: I know I could do it the ugly way and say if (cookiename1 exists) do this, if cookiename2 exists, do this.....but I'm sure there is a cleaner way.

Comment: Use 2 level deep arrays? Stringify and parse when retrieving the cookie